# What is the reason Light Sport Aircraft (LSA) minimum speed is limited?

Tags: faa-regulations, airplane, light-sport-aircraft

I saw an explanation about Icon A5 Light Sport Airplane (LSA), it is said that according to FAA regulation, its stall speed **NOT LESS** than 45 miles per hour (mph) or around 39.1 knots or around 72 km per hour (kmph). Which is mean, its minimum speed is that 45 mph. I was curious that minimum speed is limited.

Than my question is, what is the reason FAA limits the minimum speed of an airplane? Is that stall speed limitation also applied to another type of airplane?

[image: Icon A5]
[Photo source](https://www.aircharterservice.de/en/about-us/news-features/blog/is-it-a-boat-is-it-a-plane-a-look-at-the-icon-a5):

**Edit:** Some conversion from mph to knot was not clear. Should be 45mph or 39.1 knots.
**Edit 2**: I added the minimum speed not less than 45mph.

Comment: Your edit is incorrect. The regulation says the stall speed can be **no greater than** 45kt for an LSA.

Comment: Can you provide your source?  Obviously, either Icon got it wrong, or you read it wrong.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks "why is (untrue statement) the rule?"  The entire premise of the question, "stall speed no ***lower*** than X" is false.

Comment: I am back on the close wagon.  Especially since the OP hasn’t even bothered to enlighten us to the source of the error.  (I searched the Icon A5 website and couldn’t find anything). Perpetuating misinformation benefits nobody.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a faulty premise.

Answer (score 6):

The FAA mandates a maximum to the stall speed, not a minimum. The minimum speed must not be higher than a given value.

The minimum speed is limited in order to reduce the risk and severity of accidents, especially during landing. The same was used in FAR 23 where a speed limit of 61 knots was mandated for singe-engined aircraft and multi-engined aircraft of 6000 lbs MTOW or less (§23.49 (6)c).

A slower stall speed translates into a slower approach speed and shorter landing distance. Both help to prevent accidents by giving the pilot more time to get the landing right and come to a stop without crashing. Also, the energy involved is smaller so if something goes wrong the accident is more survivable.

Comment: Sorry Peter for my unclear. According to the explanation from the Icon A5, stall speed should not less than 45 mph. Mean, can not be 40mph, but it is alowed to be abouve 45 mph. This is a big question for me, as you said, lower will be saver. That also actually my question, why.

Comment: @MichaelHall: Thank you for explaining your downvote.

Comment: @Peter Kampf, downvote removed based on your edit.

Answer (score 4):

The FAA’s regulations (14 CFR 1.1, “light sport aircraft”, paragraph 4) require a stall speed **no higher than** 45kt (51mph) for a plane to be certified as a Light Sport Aircraft. This is a maximum value, not a minimum.

The stall speed is the lowest speed at which the wing generates lift. Below this speed, the plane essentially stops flying and Bad Things(tm) happen, like people dying.

It seems logical that an airplane with a lower stall speed would be safer for sport pilots, who do not need to have as much training as private (or higher) pilots. Flying slower means that things happen in the cockpit at a slower pace, there is more time to correct mistakes and if there is an accident, it will hopefully be less severe.

Ideally, all planes would have a very low stall speed for safety. However, wings designed for higher maximum speeds necessarily have higher stall speeds as well, and that means pilots need more training than a sport pilot gets to be allowed to fly faster planes.

Comment: "The stall speed is the minimum speed at which the wing generates lift." This is a bit too much oversimplified. I'm aware you are trying to keep it as simple as possible for this question, but you should at least add that this refers to level flight. A plane can stall at any airspeed and any attitude.

Comment: Stall speed is a minimum speed. Mean, the airplane will stop flying if the speed less than that. My question is very clear, the reason: What is the reason FAA limits the minimum speed of an airplane?

Comment: @AirCraftLover Not sure what's unclear to you. This answer says exactly why: "lower stall speed would be safer for sport pilots".

Comment: @AirCraftLover - As Bianfable has stated, the FAA has mandated built in safety margins into an aircraft with the intention of it being flown by pilots with possibly less time, currency, or proficiency. Poor ADM, IMC, and Stalls/Spins account for a lot of fatalities in GA. LSA regulations limit a lot of the factors which contribute to this. Lower stall speed, less impetus from a lower weight, and a lower passenger capacity help to limit the fatalities for those flying as well as those on the ground.

Comment: @Bianfable, the 45 mph is the minimum, not the maximum. Maximum is can be any speed. As I said, **FAA limits the minimum speed of an airplane**. But why?

Comment: @AirCraftLover I know, the FAA limits the **maximum value** for the **stall speed** (which by the way is not your minimum speed, you never fly at the stall speed, usually approach speed is 1.3 times the stall speed). And as explained in the answer they limit this because a lower speed means you are safer (accidents are less likely, and less severe).

Comment: @MichaelHall This is obviously wrong! Nobody restricts the stall speed to be greater than something. The limit for LSA is that it cannot be larger than 45 knots (51 mph). See e.g. [here](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/airplane_handbook/media/18_afh_ch16.pdf)

Comment: @AirCraftLover You are misunderstanding the limit as a minimum, whereas it is actually a maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your edit. It helps to explain your misunderstanding. A link to the “explanation about Icon A5” would help even more. Nowhere in the link to your photo source does it mention what you said.

As others have stated, the FAA regulations that define a Light Sport Aircraft specify the **maximum** stall speed the aircraft must have to be certified. That **maximum** stall speed is 45 knots indicated airspeed. As a matter of fact, I have flown LSAs with stall speeds of 35 and 31 knots. There is an excerpt from Title 14 Code of Federal Regulations Part 1.1 below.

The confusion lies in the usage of the term “minimum steady flight speed“. If you read the excerpt careful, you may interpret this as a **maximum** limit as well. The **minimum** speed at which the aircraft can maintain steady straight and level, unaccelerated flight must be a **maximum** of 45 knots. It has to be able to maintain steady flight at an airspeed at or below 45 knots. In other words, if the aircraft can not maintain steady flight in the airspeed range between 46 to 120 knots, it can not be certified as an LSA.

> **Light-sport aircraft** means an aircraft, other than a helicopter or powered-lift that, since its original certification, has continued to meet the following:
>
> (1) A maximum takeoff weight of not more than—
>
> (i) 1,320 pounds (600 kilograms) for aircraft not intended for operation on water; or
>
> (ii) 1,430 pounds (650 kilograms) for an aircraft intended for operation on water.
>
> (2) A maximum airspeed in level flight with maximum continuous power (VH) of not more than 120 knots CAS under standard atmospheric conditions at sea level.
>
> (3) A maximum never-exceed speed (VNE) of not more than 120 knots CAS for a glider.
>
> (4) A maximum stalling speed or minimum steady flight speed without the use of lift-enhancing devices (VS1) of not more than 45 knots CAS at the aircraft’s maximum certificated takeoff weight and most critical center of gravity.
>
> (5) A maximum seating capacity of no more than two persons, including the pilot.
>
> (6) A single, reciprocating engine, if powered.
>
> (7) A fixed or ground-adjustable propeller if a powered aircraft other than a powered glider.
>
> (8) A fixed or feathering propeller system if a powered glider.
>
> (9) A fixed-pitch, semi-rigid, teetering, two-blade rotor system, if a gyroplane.
>
> (10) A nonpressurized cabin, if equipped with a cabin.
>
> (11) Fixed landing gear, except for an aircraft intended for operation on water or a glider.
>
> (12) Fixed or retractable landing gear, or a hull, for an aircraft intended for operation on water.
>
> (13) Fixed or retractable landing gear for a glider.